# LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS option returns -1 instead of 1

Tags: php, ldap, openldap, referrals

So i am trying to write to an LDAP server, however i am receiving a `code 10  : Referral` back. So i thought i should try to make my application able to follow the referral and then maybe the problem would be solved.

Sadly though when i set the `LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS` option to `true` . When i try to get that option instead of being `1` its `-1` and the rebind process does not continue.

```
$connection = ldap_connect('somehost', 9999);
ldap_set_option($connection,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, true);

ldap_get_option($connection,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, $ref_option);
var_dump($ref_option); // => -1
```

This is very weird as it should be `1`. I think that this also affects my issue rebinding to the referral server.

Is this functionality correct ?

What could affect the `ldap_get_option` of the `LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS` that makes it return `-1`?

Comment: What's the result of `ldap_set_option`?  It should return `true` on success.

Comment: Indeed the result of `ldap_set_option` is true, meaning that the option was set successfully.